# I can only have 20 images when using RecyclerView, Glide, Volley and ImageView

Tags: android-recyclerview

Recently I want to see the source code of Glide, Volley, Okhttp, I feel that I have not used it well. I used it today.
and I don’t understandEven Recycler was not familiar with it and found it for several hours. Finally, the picture is displayed, but the problem is that there are only 20, more than 20 is to prompt java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 20, Size: 20
Kotlin for language

This is MainActivity

```
package com.example.simpledemo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager
import com.android.volley.Request
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue
import com.android.volley.Response
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley
import com.google.gson.Gson

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var pixabayViewModel: PixabayViewModel


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val recyclerViewAdapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
        pixabayViewModel = ViewModelProvider(
            this,
            ViewModelProvider.NewInstanceFactory()
        ).get(PixabayViewModel::class.java)



        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerview)
        recyclerView.also {
            it.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
            it.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        }

        fetchPixabay()

        pixabayViewModel.mutableLiveData.observe(this, Observer {
            recyclerViewAdapter.pixabay = it
        })

    }

    fun fetchPixabay() {
        val gsonUrl =
            "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=17425373-62ef439ab473aae9eebbb9533&q=yellow+flowers&image_type=photo&pretty=true"
        val stringRequest = StringRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            gsonUrl,
            Response.Listener {
                pixabayViewModel.mutableLiveData.value =
                    Gson().fromJson(it, Pixabay::class.java)

            },
            Response.ErrorListener {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "fetchPixabay: request error:$it")
            })

        Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext).add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

这是Pixabay.kt

```
package com.example.simpledemo

import android.os.Parcelable
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize
data class Pixabay(
    val total:Int,
    val totalHits:Int,
    val hits: ArrayList<Hit>
)
@Parcelize
data class Hit(
    @SerializedName("id") var id: Int,
    @SerializedName("webformatURL") var webformatURL: String
) : Parcelable
```

This is RecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.demo

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.img_object.view.*
import java.util.zip.Inflater

class RecyclerViewAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder>() {
    lateinit var pixabay:Pixabay

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.img_object, parent,false)
        return MyViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = pixabay.total

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        Log.i("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder: $position")
//        Log.i("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder: ${pixabay.total}")
//        Log.i("Adapter", "onBindViewHolder: ${pixabay.totalHits}")
        Glide.with(holder.itemView).load(pixabay.hits.get(position).webformatURL)
            .into(holder.itemView.imageView)
    }

}

class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
```

There is only one ConstraintLayout in activity_main, and only one RecyclerView in ConstraintLayout. The adapter is adapted with img_object. There is only one ImageView inside

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that pixabay default per_page=20